# Running two Timer simultaneously

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, multithreading, timer

I am developing an app that randomly select two **CollectionView** cells simultaneously. I have achieved that in android by adding different Runnables to Handler. 
In iOS selecting one cell is working perfectly fine with this code:

```
let randomNumber1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numberOfItems)))
        print("random1",randomNumber1)
        let indexPath1 = IndexPath.init(row: randomNumber1, section: 0)
        self.previousIndexpath1 = indexPath1
        self.collectionView(self.imageCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath1)
        myTimer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.5), target: self, selector: #selector(AdvanceCollectionViewController.selectRow1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        let deadlineTime1 = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime1, execute: {
            self.myTimer1.invalidate()
          //  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "collectionToDetail", sender: self)
        })
```

Now I want run the timer for two threads and display their index at end of deadline. For that I just added this code which creates another thread:

```
  let randomNumber2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numberOfItems)))
        print("random2",randomNumber2)
        let indexPath2 = IndexPath.init(row: randomNumber2, section: 0)
        self.previousIndexpath2 = indexPath2
        self.collectionView(self.imageCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath2)
        myTimer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.5), target: self, selector: #selector(AdvanceCollectionViewController.selectRow2), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        let deadlineTime2 = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime2, execute: {
            self.myTimer2.invalidate()
            //  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "collectionToDetail", sender: self)
        })
```

When viewing the log I can get log for both of thread. But UI Cell Selection does not appear to select two cells. I am new to iOS so not much aware of multithreading/mulitple timers in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line only called the delegate method:

```
self.collectionView(self.imageCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath1)
```

If you want to select the item in UI, you have to call another method like the following:

```
self.imageCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath1, animated: false, scrollPosition: .bottom)
```

You may want to set the property as well:

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```